# Snowflake SQL Escape *

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to compile a query that is using the replace() function.
The value to be replaced is a * .

My expression such as this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MY_DB.MY_SCHEMA.MYFUNCTION(
"P_ONE" STRING, 
"P_TWO" STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE SQL
AS '
select replace(
               replace(VALUE,'\*',''),
               '.txt','') 
               from MY_DB.MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE where SUBJECT = 'somevalue'
'
```

fails with

Syntax error: unexpected '*'. (line xx)

The escape character \  doesn't seem to have any effect?

Is there an alterative using an ASCII value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_replace).

`select REGEXP_REPLACE('A*B','\\*','') as NEWVAL`

or using hexadecimal literals:

`select REGEXP_REPLACE('A*B','\\x2a','') as NEWVAL`

| NEWVAL |
| --- |
| AB |

Comment: select REPLACE('A\*B','\*','') as newval also appears to work, so not sure the cause of your error.